# How to avoid one-hot encoding for LinearModelFit and NonlinearModelFit

Tags: fitting, machine-learning

This code works:

```
data = {
   {"a", 1, 1.0},
   {"a", 2, 3.0},
   {"b", 3, 2.0},
   {"b", 3, 2.3}
   };
g[type_] := 
  If[type == "a", pType["a"], If[type == "b", pType["b"], 1]];
 model = NonlinearModelFit[
   data,
   g[type] * pA,
   {pType["a"], pType["b"], pA },
   {type, x1}
   ];
model["BestFitParameters"]
(* gives {pType["a"] -> 1.10184, pType["b"] -> 1.18448, pA -> 1.81515} *)
```

but this doesn't:

```
Clear[g];
typeParams = <| "a" -> pType["a"], "b" -> pType["b"]|>;
g[type_String] := Lookup[typeParams, type, 1.0];
 model = NonlinearModelFit[
   data,
   g[type] * pA,
   {pType["a"], pType["b"], pA },
   {type, x1}
   ];
model["BestFitParameters"] 

(* GOT:
FindFit::fitm: Unable to solve for the fit parameters; 
the design matrix is nonrectangular, non-numerical, 
or could not be inverted. 
*)
```

UPDATE: And this gives wrong answer:

```
typeParams = <|"a" -> pType["a"], "b" -> pType["b"]|>;
g[type_] := Lookup[typeParams, type, 1.0];
model = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, 
  g[type]*pA, 
  {pType["a"], pType["b"], pA}, 
  {type, x1}
];
model["BestFitParameters"]
(* gives wrong answer {pType["a"] -> 0., pType["b"] -> 0., pA -> 2.075} *)
```

END UPDATE

I have categorial feature with lots of values (10K+ or  1M+) and I don't want to use neither one-hot encoding, nor nested IFs in definition of g function.

Is there any way to get easy to inspect linear model with big categorial features? I tried Predict, but it's not easy to inspect the result, because of different pre, post processors.

Answer (score 4):

Look at your code. The difference causing the error is:

```
g[type_]
g[type_String]
```

MMA evaluates arguments before sending them to a function. In the first case `g[type]` gets evaluated, returning If[...], what obviously can be used by MMA.

In the second case `g[type]` is not evaluated as "type" is not a string. Subsequently MMA proceeds with `g[type]` instead of the association what leads to an error.

You may verify this by adding "String" to the first case, and you will also get the error.

Comment: I know it. Case g[type_] gives wrong answer. Lookup is early evaluated and g[type] = 1 and no optimization occures

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get easy to inspect linear model with big categorial features?

I would say just use your original implementation by turning the association into one "big if-else" statement:

```
Clear[G];
data = {{"a", 1, 1.0}, {"a", 2, 3.0}, {"b", 3, 2.0}, {"b", 3, 2.3}};
typeParams = <|"a" -> pType["a"], "b" -> pType["b"]|>; 
G[type_] := Evaluate[Switch @@ Join[Prepend[KeyValueMap[## &, typeParams], type], {_String, 1}]];
model = NonlinearModelFit[data, G[type]*pA, {Sequence @@ Values[typeParams], pA}, {type, x1}];
model["BestFitParameters"]
```

Here is an example with larger, randomly generated data:

```
Clear[G];
SeedRandom[2323];
k = 20;
typeParams = Association@Map[# -> pType[#] &, RandomWord[k]];
data = MapThread[Prepend, {RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4 k, 2}], RandomChoice[Keys[typeParams], 4 k]}];
ResourceFunction["RecordsSummary"][data]
```

[image]

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 G[type_] := Evaluate[Switch @@ Join[Prepend[KeyValueMap[## &, typeParams], type], {_String, 1}]];
 model = NonlinearModelFit[data, G[type]*pA, {Sequence @@ Values[typeParams], pA}, {type, x1}]; 
 model["BestFitParameters"]
]

(* {0.032431, {pType["whereupon"] -> 0.824234, 
  pType["kW"] -> 1.34909, pType["coreligionist"] -> 1.28158, 
  pType["scurrilously"] -> 1.00538, pType["floodgate"] -> 0.700137, 
  pType["septuagenarian"] -> 0.396706, pType["reinforce"] -> 0.834465,
   pType["wither"] -> 0.100641, pType["shoeshine"] -> 0.824873, 
  pType["achievable"] -> 0.63437, pType["ta"] -> 0.821303, 
  pType["medley"] -> 0.767102, pType["galvanism"] -> 0.86347, 
  pType["beaded"] -> 0.950551, pType["botanic"] -> 1.07446, 
  pType["fleeting"] -> 0.767732, pType["nave"] -> 0.679813, 
  pType["considerately"] -> 0.557778, pType["entice"] -> 0.356292, 
  pType["educative"] -> 1., pA -> 0.653949}} *)
```

I tried the code above with 200 and 800 variables. (Takes much longer time, 15 s and 2500 s respectively.)

[image]